# Multiplication of data in a hierarchy (oracle)

Tags: oracle, hierarchy

I'm working on a project and i'm facing some difficulties. I'am able now to retreive data but i must use it in a calulation.

My actual code is :

```
with tree as
(
select AA.PORTEFEUILLE, AA.fonds, round(AA.nbreparts ,  7) parts, opcvm, level lev
, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(fonds, '/') Path
, connect_by_root(fonds) leaf
, connect_by_root(AA.nbreparts) detenus
from dbo.chiffres  AA 
connect by  fonds= prior opcvm  

)

select distinct tree.Portefeuille,  lev, path, 
round(detenus/cc.nombre_parts_av_vl,7) weight, CC.frais
from tree
inner join dbo.histo_portef_fp_group CC on leaf=CC.portefeuille 
and CC.date_fp = to_date('25/03/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

The resulat i'm getting now is:

```
Portefeuille || LEV || Path ||  weight || frais

5000         || 1   || /010  || 0,73%      || 100
5000         || 2   || /001/010 ||  0,39%  || 300
5000         || 2   || /013/010 || 0,09%    || 200
5000         || 3   || 211/013/010 || 2,79%  || 150
```

But the final resulat that i want is:

```
Portefeuille || LEV || Path ||  total

5000         || 3   || 211/013/010 || 0,73%*100 + 0,73%*0,09%*200 + 0,73%*0,09%*2,79%+150
5000         || 2   || /001/010   || 0,73%*100 + 0,73%*0,39%*300
```

I'm using 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE chiffres(
  Portefeuille nvarchar2(255),
  Fonds        nvarchar2(255),
  nbreparts    float,
  opcvm        nvarchar2(255)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE histo_portef_fp_group(
  Portefeuille       nvarchar2(255),
  date_fp            DATE,
  nombre_parts_av_vl float,
  frais float
);
```

and an example of data to get the result above:

```
INSERT INTO chiffres(Portefeuille,Fonds,nbreparts,opcvm)
VALUES('5000','010',380, null);

INSERT INTO chiffres(Portefeuille,Fonds,nbreparts,opcvm)
VALUES('104827','211',3800,'013');

INSERT INTO chiffres(Portefeuille,Fonds, nbreparts,opcvm)
VALUES('104823','013',3,'010');

INSERT INTO chiffres(Portefeuille,Fonds, nbreparts,opcvm)
VALUES('104823','001',302,'010');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO histo_portef_fp_group(Portefeuille,date_fp,  nombre_parts_av_vl, frais)
VALUES('010', DATE '2016-03-25',52224, 100);

INSERT INTO histo_portef_fp_group(Portefeuille,date_fp, nombre_parts_av_vl, frais)
VALUES('013',DATE '2016-03-25',3175, 200);

INSERT INTO histo_portef_fp_group(Portefeuille,date_fp, nombre_parts_av_vl, frais)
VALUES('211',DATE '2016-03-25',136354, 150);

INSERT INTO histo_portef_fp_group(Portefeuille,date_fp, nombre_parts_av_vl, frais)
VALUES('001',DATE '2016-03-25',76449, 300);
```

Comment: Add `WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` just after `connect by  fonds= prior opcvm `

Comment: Please can you post a [MCVE] (i.e. the DDL statement for your tables and the DML for some example data that matches your output).

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid. The alias `AA` is on the inner select and cannot be referenced in the outer select and there are unmatched round brackets. Please fix it and give us some sample data.

Comment: I tried to simplify so i deleted a part of the code, i'm going to correct this.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I corrected the code and added some clarifications. Please let me know if you need other details. thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is Oracle? The DDL and DML statements have SQL Server syntax and are invalid in Oracle.

Comment: The query is still invalid as there is no `FRAIS` column in the `histo_portef_fp_group` table.

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm new on oracle, i work with sql server in my machine right now, but i must work with oracle for my project at work. I'm sorry, i'm going to try to correct the DDL and DML.

Comment: I've converted the DDL & DML to Oracle syntax but you still need to fix the issue that there is no `FRAIS` column in the `histo_portef_fp_group` table.

Comment: I added frais to the ddl and dml.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

```
WITH data ( fonds, opcvm, portefeuille, lvl, path, weight, frais, isleaf ) AS (
  SELECT fonds,
         opcvm,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( c.portefeuille ),
         LEVEL,
         SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( fonds, '/' ),
         ROUND( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( c.nbreparts ) / h.nombre_parts_av_vl, 7 ),
         frais,
         CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF
  FROM   chiffres c
         INNER JOIN
         histo_portef_fp_group h
         ON ( c.fonds = h.portefeuille )
  START WITH opcvm IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR fonds = opcvm
)
SELECT portefeuille,
       lvl,
       path,
       ( SELECT SUM(
                  ( SELECT EXP(SUM(LN(weight)))
                    FROM   data ddd
                    START WITH ddd.fonds = dd.fonds
                    CONNECT BY PRIOR opcvm = fonds
                  )
                  * frais
                )
         FROM   data dd
         START WITH dd.fonds = d.fonds
         CONNECT BY PRIOR opcvm = fonds ) AS total
FROM   data d
WHERE  isleaf = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
PORTEFEUILLE LVL PATH         TOTAL
------------ --- ------------ ----------
5000           2 /010/001     .738480273 
5000           3 /010/013/211 .902166845
```

Comment: Thank you very much MT0, i'm going to test this solution tomorrow at work.